# No rviz interface

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm having trouble running rviz. I first start roscore in a terminal window, then open another terminal and execute 'rosrun rviz rviz.' The loading screen shows up, but the actual program interface never appears. No errors are reported. And if I run 'top' in another terminal, it looks like rviz is actually running, but it's just not visible. \

I should probably mention that I used to have cturtle and diamondback installed and I recently removed cturtle. I'm also running ubuntu 11.04.

Any help would be appreciated!

~Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9979/no-rviz-interface/) by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-01**:
Well, ROS has just been updated for 11.04 http://www.ros.org/news/2011/06/ros-packages-now-available-for-ubuntu-natty.html :)

**Comment by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on 2011-06-01**:
I checked and didn't see anything. I ended up just going back to using Ubuntu 10.10 and everything is fine again.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-05-18**:
There should be printouts in the terminal or logfile. Is there anything about GLX missing or similar?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-17**:
You can also add details by editing the original question btw.

**Comment by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on 2011-05-17**:
I should probably mention that I used to have cturtle and diamondback installed and I recently removed cturtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dornhege: Well, ROS has just been updated for 11.04 http://www.ros.org/news/2011/06/ros-packages-now-available-for-ubuntu-natty.html

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0